# Unable to load model trained on Pytotch version 1.6.0 in Pytorch version 1.5.1

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, kaggle

I have recently updated my Pytorch version to `1.6.0` on my local machine to use their mixed-precision training, since then I am encountering this issue, I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tweet-sentiment-extraction/discussion/157695#886125), but it is still throwing below error.

```
RuntimeError: version_ <= kMaxSupportedFileFormatVersion INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1591914880026/work/caffe2/serialize/inline_container.cc:132, please report a bug to PyTorch. Attempted to read a PyTorch file with version 4, but the maximum supported version for reading is 3. Your PyTorch installation may be too old.
```

Link to reproduce: https://www.kaggle.com/rohitsingh9990/error-reproducing-code?scriptVersionId=37468859

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: A workaround is to use `torch.load` in the newer PyTorch and then re-save with `_use_new_zipfile_serialization=False`

Answer (score 0):

In `torch.__version__ == 1.6.0` :

`torch.save(model_.state_dict(), 'best_model.pth.tar', use_new_zipfile_serialization=False)`

then in `torch.__version__ == 1.5.1`:

`torch.load('best_model.pth.tar',map_location='cpu')`